# Unable to change files/folder attributes on NAS sharing through samba server

Tags: samba, cifs, nas

My situation:

- Client (Windows 10) -> Server (Debian 10 / Samba Version 4.9.5-Debian) -> NAS (Lenovo ix2)
- From Client (Windows 10), I can create, rename, delete, change files and folders without any problem but I cannot retrieve DOS/Windows Files Attribute information (read-write, Hide, System) or set it !
- Windows 10 have SMBv1 enabled
- Server Debian is updated to 10.10 from 8 (new hardware machine, clean installation, from scratch) ; with version 8.0 the problem was not there.
- Server mount - via `fstab`, but is the same with prompt - NAS share with:

  ```
  //NAS/STORAGE  /mnt/STORAGE  cifs  username=...,password=...,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,uid=...,gid=...,noauto,noserverino,nounix,vers=1.0
  ```

  I have tried `vers=2.0`, `vers=3.0`, and many other... and omit option, but nothing
- Server (Debian 10) mount (on "/mnt" path subfolder) many other windows sharing (Window 10, Windows 7, Windows NT 4.0) and I haven't any problem, only on NAS (Lenovo ix2) not working properly.
- `smb.conf`:

  ```
  [global]
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  # *** I have tried many parameter for protocol:
  #client min protocol = SMB2
  #server min protocol = SMB2
  #client max protocol = NT1
  #server max protocol = NT1
  #max protocol = NT1
  interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp11s0f0 enp11s0f1 10.9.8.1
  bind interfaces only = yes
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  server role = standalone server
  netbios name = PIGRECO
  server string = Distributed File Server - Samba %v (%h)
  interfaces = lo enp11s0f0 enp11s0f1
  local master = yes
  domain master = yes
  preferred master = yes
  os level = 35
  encrypt passwords = yes
  smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
  guest account = studio
  ldap ssl = no
  client lanman auth = yes
  client plaintext auth = yes
  wins support = yes
  dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree

  [COMMON]
  comment = Common PIGRECO Archive
  path = /mnt
  force user = studio
  read only = No
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  guest ok = Yes
  hosts allow = 192.168.0. 172.0.0. 10.9.8.
  strict locking = No
  browsable = Yes
  # The "ea support" set to "no" don't solve the problem:
  #ea support = no
  vfs objects = recycle
  recycle:repository = /mnt/STORAGE/Trash
  recycle:keeptree = Yes
  recycle:versions = Yes
  recycle:maxsize = 104857600
  ```
- I have tried the CIFS debug (with `echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI` ) and get this error:

  ```
  Status code returned 0xc000004f NT_STATUS_EAS_NOT_SUPPORTED
  ```

  but i cannot find any information online.
- In `/mnt` I have created new sub-folder for NAS, like other folder (permission and owner) but only read/write file creation permission is influenced when I change linux attrib/owner.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this settings for samba config file (`/etc/samba/smb.conf`):

```
[global]
  client min protocol = SMB2_10
  client max protocol = SMB3_11
  
  client ipc min protocol = SMB2_10
  client ipc max protocol = SMB3_11

  server min protocol = SMB2_10
  server max protocol = SMB3_11

  map readonly = permissions
  store dos attributes = no
```

And now, I'm able to change files permissions from Windows 7/10 .

Answer (score 0):

DOS attributes can be stored either in filesystem Extended Attributes (if the underlying filesystem can handle them) or as maps onto traditional UNIX file permission bits

This combination *should* use an Extended Attribute where possible, and fall back to UNIX file permission bits otherwise:

```
store dos attributes = yes    ; Default yes
map archive = yes             ; Default yes
map hidden = yes              ; Default no
map readonly = yes            ; Default no
map system = yes              ; Default no
```

Since the default is already to store dos attributes, and this isn't working for you, it's possible that your underlying filesystem can't handle extended attributes and you may need to set `store dos attributes = no`.

Note that the man page (see `man smb.conf`) writes that,

> On Linux the filesystem must have been mounted with the mount option `user_xattr` in order for extended attributes to work, also extended attributes must be compiled into the Linux kernel.

Perhaps this is the underlying reason that storing DOS attributes isn't working for you.

On an entirely unrelated note, SMBv1 has been deprecated and you shouldn't need to be using it anymore. If you need, you can have your server accept SMBv1 (as well as later versions), but Windows 10 will prefer to use SMBv3 before dropping down to the older levels.